# Integer eigenvectors of a rational matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, integer-programming

I have a $2n\times 2n$ rational matrix  $A$ for which I know can be diagonalized in the form

$$A=MDM^{-1}$$

where $D$ is a $2n\times 2n$ matrix consisting of half eigenvalues $1$ and half eigenvalues $0$. The eigenvectors can then be expressed in terms of the rows of $M$.

I.e. we have $n$ eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$ of the form

$$DM^{-1}v=\lambda M^{-1} v$$

Hence, $v=M\vec e_1$.

I therefore have $n$ degenerate $2n$-vectors which correspond to the first $n$ rows of $M$. However, I would like to identify all possible integer eigenvectors.

In the case of integer matirx $A$ this would be a linear Diophantine equation and so we could use the Smith normal form to find $B=UAV$ where $B$ is a diagonal matrix and $U,V$ are unimodular.

One way could be to convert $A$ to an integer matrix by multiplying it by the greatest common divisor of all the denominators in $A$ but I wonder if this would mean we would lose possible eigenvectors.

Otherwise is there perhaps a way to select only the eigenspace of $v$ for which all $v_i$ are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of multiplying the matrix $\ A\ $ by the least common multiple (not the greatest common divisor) of the denominators of its entries will  work.  If $\ \sigma\ $ is the least common multiple of the denominators of the entries of $\ A\ $, and  $\ B=\sigma UAV\ $ is the Smith normal form of $\ \sigma A\ $, where $\ U\ $ and $\ V\ $ are unimodular matrices, then the first $\ n\ $ entries on the diagonal of $\ B\ $ will be non-zero and the rest will be zero. Therefore $\ \sigma UAV\vec{e}_i=B\vec{e}_i=0\ $ for $\ i=n,n+1,\dots,2n\ $ and $\ V\vec{e}_n, V\vec{e}_{n+1},\dots,$$\,V\vec{e}_{2n}\ $ will be $\ n\ $ linearly independent eigenvectors of $\ A\ $ with integer entries for the eigenvalue $\ 0\ $.

Also, if $\ \vec{w}\ $ is *any* eigenvector of $\ A\ $ for the eigenvalue $\ 0\ $, with integer entries, then $\ 0=\sigma UAVV^{-1}\vec{w}=BV^{-1}\vec{w}\ $.  Because the first $\ n\ $ entries on the diagonal of $\ B\ $ are non-zero, the first $\ n\ $ entries of $\ V^{-1}\vec{w}\ $ must be zero. Therefore
$$
V^{-1}\vec{w}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\\vdots\\0\\z_n\\z_{n+1}\\\vdots\\z_{2n}}=\sum_{i=n}^{2n}z_i\vec{e}_i\ ,
$$
where $\ z_i\in\mathbb{Z}\ $, because the entries of $\ V^{-1}\ $ and $\ w\ $ are all integers.  Therefore
$$
w=\sum_{i=n}^{2n}z_iV\vec{e}_i
$$
is an integer linear combination of the eigenvectors $\ V\vec{e}_n,$$\, V\vec{e}_{n+1},\dots,$$\,V\vec{e}_{2n}\ $. It follows that $\ V\vec{e}_n,$$\, V\vec{e}_{n+1},\dots,$$\,V\vec{e}_{2n}\ $ is a set of generators for the $\ \mathbb{Z}$-module of eigenvectors of $\ A\ $ with integer entries for the eigenvalue $\ 0\ $

Likewise, if you do the same thing with the matrix $\ A-I\ $, you'll get a set of $\ n\ $ generators with integer entries for the $\ \mathbb{Z}$-module of eigenvectors of $\ A\ $ with integer entries for the eigenvalue $\ 1\ $.

If you don't need the eigenvectors to form a set of generators, there's a slightly simpler way of getting a set of $\ n\ $ with integer entries that are merely linearly independent over the rationals.  Solving the sets of linear equations $\ Ax=0\ $ and $\ (A-I)y=0\ $ by [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) will give you bases of the two eigenspaces with *rational* entries. If you now multiply each member of these bases by the least common multiple of the denominators of their entries, you'll get $\ n\ $ linearly independent eigenvectors with integer entries for each of the two eigenvalues.

Comment: why should the number of non-zero entries in $B$ equal the number of non-signular values? It makes intuitive sense, but I can't find a proof that this is the case

Comment: Or I guess in this case its that even the eigenvalues of A are equal to the elements of B? (By the method you refer to in the first paragraph, which is more convenient for my needs)

Comment: The product of a matrix and any non-singular matrix must have the  same rank as that of the original matrix, so both  $\ A\ $ and  $\ B\ $ must have the same rank, namely $\ n\ $, as $\ D\ $, and the rank of $\ B\ $ is just the number of its non-zero entries.  The entries of $\ B\ $ will not usually be the eigenvalues of $\ A\ $.

Comment: I am wondering if the second method ensures we include all vectors, for example, if we do Gaussian elimination and find v_1=(1,0,1/2) and v_2=(0,2,1/2) then we would convert them to v_1'=(2,0,1) and v_2'=(0,4,1). Clearly v_1+v2=(1,2,1) is an integer eigenvector but there is no way to combine v_1' and v_2' to get v_1+v_2

Comment: $\ (1,2,1)=\frac{1}{2}(2,0,1)+\frac{1}{2}(0,4,1)\ $, so you *can* combine $\ v_1'+v_2'\ $ to get $\ v_1+v_2\ $, but you need to use *non-integer* rational coefficients to do so.  You just can't do it with *integer* coefficients.  The second method will give you a set of $\ n\ $ linearly independent eigenvectors with integer coefficients that will form a basis of the eigenspace considered as a *vector space over the rationals*.  However, they're unlikely to form a *generating set* for the $\ \mathbb{Z}$-module consisting of the vectors in the eigenspace with integer entries.

Comment: The first method, however, will give you a generating set for the  $\ \mathbb{Z}$-module consisting of the vectors in the eigenspace with integer entries, so if you need such a generating set, you should stick to the first method.

Comment: Okay great, but how do we prove that the first method does give a generating set? Again it seems to work, but I am unsure of how to construct a proof. I can also start a new question if it is easier

Comment: No need for a separate question. I've added a proof that your method of using the Smith normal form will give you a generating set.